# SQL Where/From clause optimization (sql-server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am currently dealing with a 3 minute 47 seconds execution time in a report query. I am really pushing to try and get this execution under a minute. This where clause is taking up 66% in the execution plan.

This Where clause is most definitley the culprit after following through the execution plan.

Is it bad practice to have these type of data filters in the Where clause? If so should I try and combine this with my inner join statements in FROM Clause to speed up execution?

```
select txtPolicyNum
      ,Sum(CASE WHEN txtDebitCredit='d' THEN txtAmt*-1 ELSE txtAmt END) As Prem
into #prem
from proddw.dbo.miscGLHistory
where Left(txtAccountNum,1)='3'
Group by txtPolicyNum
Order by txtPolicyNum




SELECT 
ad.txtAgentNum GAAgentNum,
AgentNum.txtAgentNum Agent_Num,
rtrim(AgentNum.txtPriFName)+ ' ' + rtrim(AgentNum.txtPriLName) as Agent_Name,

mainDim.txtFHMainNum as MainBranch, 
fd.txtFHNum as FH_Num,
fd.txtPriName as FH_Name,
iv.txtPolNum as PolicyNum, 
rtrim(oi.txtIndFirst)+' '+rtrim(oi.txtIndLast) As Insured_Name,
iv.txtProdType as Product,
Substring(iv.txtPlanCode,4,2)+' ' + Substring(iv.txtPlanCode,6,3) as Plan_At_Issue,
Convert(date,iv.datCycleDate,102) IssueDate, 
CASE WHEN iv.intCount=0 THEN 'Rider'
     WHEN iv.intCount=1 THEN 'NewIss'
     ELSE 'Policy Adjustment' end as Type, 
iv.decPaidPAP+iv.decPaidPAA AS Funeral_Amt,
iv.decProdVal AS Face, 
CASE WHEN Substring(iv.txtPlanCode,6,3) = 'ROP' THEN p.Prem * 1.05
     ELSE iv.decProdVal END as Current_Death_Benefit, 
iv.intIssAge as Age,
rtrim(oe.txtIndFirst)+' '+rtrim(oe.txtIndLast) As Owner_Name


INTO #StepOne
FROM proddw.dbo.IssVal as iv 
inner join proddw.dbo.AgentRef ar on iv.intAgentRefID = ar.intAgentRefID
inner join proddw.dbo.AgentDim AgentNum on ar.intAgentID = AgentNum.intAgentID
--Getting Agent NUM

inner join proddw.dbo.GARef agt on iv.intGARefID = agt.intGARefID
inner join proddw.dbo.AgentDim ad on agt.intAgentID=ad.intAgentID
--Getting GA NUM
--These Fields Are Populating Correctly

--Getting FH Num
inner join proddw.dbo.FHRef fr on iv.intFHRefID=fr.intFHRefID
inner join proddw.dbo.FHDim fd on fr.txtFHNum=fd.txtFHNum
--Getting FHMainNum
inner join proddw.dbo.FHMainRef rm on iv.intFHMainRefID=rm.intFHMainRefID
inner join proddw.dbo.FHDim mainDim on rm.txtFHMainNum=mainDim.txtFHMainNum
--Getting InsuredName
inner join proddw.dbo.InsRef ir on iv.intInsRefID=ir.intInsRefID
inner join proddw.dbo.OwnInsBeneDim oi on ir.intID=oi.intID
--Getting PolOwnerName
inner join proddw.dbo.OwnRef orw on iv.intPolOwnerRefID = orw.intOwnRefID
inner join proddw.dbo.OwnInsBeneDim oe on orw.intID = oe.intID

   inner JOIN #Prem p on iv.txtPolNum=p.txtPolicyNum
WHERE 
 ad.txtAgentNum='2K884' -- AND r.txtRelateCode='in' 
 AND iv.intBenSeq > 0
 and iv.txtBenType in ('BA', 'BF', 'OR')
 AND (fr.datStartDate <= iv.datCycleDate AND fr.datStopDate >= iv.datCycleDate)
 AND (rm.datStartDate <= iv.datCycleDate AND rm.datStopDate >= iv.datCycleDate)
 AND (agt.datStartDate <= iv.datCycleDate AND agt.datStopDate >=iv.datCycleDate)
 AND (ar.datStartDate <= iv.datCycleDate AND ar.datStopDate >= iv.datCycleDate)
AND (ir.datStartDate <= iv.datCycleDate AND ir.datStopDate >= iv.datCycleDate)
AND (orw.datStartDate <= iv.datCycleDate AND orw.datStopDate >= iv.datCycleDate)

GROUP BY
ad.txtAgentNum,
AgentNum.txtAgentNum,
rtrim(AgentNum.txtPriFName)+ ' ' + rtrim(AgentNum.txtPriLName),

mainDim.txtFHMainNum, 
fd.txtFHNum,
fd.txtPriName ,

iv.txtPolNum, 
rtrim(oi.txtIndFirst)+' '+rtrim(oi.txtIndLast), 
iv.txtProdType, 
Substring(iv.txtPlanCode,4,2)+' ' + Substring(iv.txtPlanCode,6,3),
rtrim(oe.txtIndFirst)+' '+rtrim(oe.txtIndLast),
iv.datCycleDate,
CASE WHEN iv.intCount=0 THEN 'SP Rider'
     WHEN iv.intCount=1 THEN 'New Issue'
     ELSE 'Policy Adjustment' end, 
iv.intCount, 
iv.intIssAge,
iv.decProdVal,
iv.decPaidPAP+iv.decPaidPAA,
CASE WHEN Substring(iv.txtPlanCode,6,3) = 'ROP' THEN p.Prem * 1.05
     ELSE iv.decProdVal END



Select s.*
from #StepOne s
order by s.PolicyNum



enter code here
```

Comment: Is it [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]? They are different products. Put into the question the complete query and also the tables definition.

Comment: You will need to provide more context. What does the actual query plan say and what indices do you have on these tables. When many tables are involved the query optimiser doesn't always work well and splitting into several statements with temp tables can run faster.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause cannot be the culprit for a lengthy query. It contains the conditions to provide the results you need. In fact, it tells the RDBMS what rows to examine and what to ignore in order to get your data. The real culprit is one or more tables that lack the appropriate indexes that help the RDBMS to filter out a lot of rows that do not match.

Comment: The query have a massive `GROUP BY` clause that also contains computed columns. No index can help a query that has computed columns in the `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: So indexing these tables won't speed up execution, and I'm probably stuck with this execution time? The group-by clause is necessary for reporting needs, so in other words 3 minutes is best I can do?

Comment: Do you even need the group by?  I don't see any aggregate functions in your select or a having clause...

Comment: The `GROUP BY` can be replaced by a simple `DISTINCT`. Your main problem might be related to the fact that your query returns duplicate rows, you probably get m:n-joins. How many rows are returned with and without aggregation?

Comment: I just replaced GROUP BY with the DISTINCT and run time is now 22 seconds (the logic eludes me)..... How do i compensate you good sir? haha can I click something to let people know you saved my life today?

Comment: Normally the optimizer should be able to rewrite GROUP BY to DISTINCT automatically, so I double checked: There are some slight differences between the SELECT and the GROUP columns, but there's also an additonal column in GROUP: `iv.intCount`. This might result in a different answer set, so please check if it's actually the same (It probably is, as the same row would be returned more than once otherwise)